# Optimizing CUDA kernel interpolation with nonuniform node points

Tags: cuda, interpolation

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have the following kernel performing an interpolation with nonuniform node points, and I would like to optimize it:

```
__global__ void interpolation(cufftDoubleComplex *Uj, double *points, cufftDoubleComplex *result, int N, int M)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    int PP;
    double P;
    const double alfa=(2.-1./cc)*pi_double-0.01;
    double phi_cap_s;
    cufftDoubleComplex temp;

    double cc_points=cc*points[i];
    double r_cc_points=rint(cc*points[i]);

    temp = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.,0.);

    if(i<M) {   
        for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
            P = (K*K-(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K))*(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K)));

            if(P>0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa*sqrt(P)))/sqrt(P));  
            if(P<0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa*sqrt(-P)))/sqrt(-P));   
            if(P==0.) phi_cap_s = alfa/pi_double;        

            PP = modulo((r_cc_points + m -K ),(cc*N)); 
            temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s*Uj[PP].x; 
            temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s*Uj[PP].y; 
        } 

        result[i] = temp; 
    }
}
```

K and cc are constants, points contains the nodes and Uj the values to be interpolated. modulo is a function basically working as %, but properly extended to negative values. For a certain arrangement, the kernel call takes 2.3ms. I have verified that the most expensive parts are

```
            if(P>0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa*sqrt(P)))/sqrt(P));  
            if(P<0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa*sqrt(-P)))/sqrt(-P));   
            if(P==0.) phi_cap_s = alfa/pi_double;
```

which takes about 40% of the total time, and

```
        PP = modulo((r_cc_points + m -K ),(cc*N)); 
        temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s*Uj[PP].x; 
        temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s*Uj[PP].y;
```

which takes about 60%. By the Visual Profiler, I have verified that the performance of the former is not influenced by the presence of the `if` statement. Please, note that I want double precision, so I'm avoiding the __exp() solution. I suspect that, for the latter, the "random" memory access Uj[PP] could be responsible of that much calculation percentage. Any suggestion on tricks or comments to reduce the computation time? Thanks in advance.

**VERSION FOLLOWING COMMENTS AND ANSWERS**

Following the suggestions kindly provided in the answers and comments, I ended up with the code below:

```
__global__ void interpolation(cufftDoubleComplex *Uj, double *points, cufftDoubleComplex *result, int N, int M)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    int PP;
    double P,tempd;
    const double alfa=(2.-1./cc)*pi_double-0.01;
    cufftDoubleComplex temp = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.,0.);

    double cc_points=cc*points[i];
    double r_cc_points=rint(cc_points);

    cufftDoubleComplex rtemp[(2*K+1)];
    double phi_cap_s[2*K+1];

    if(i<M) {   
     #pragma unroll //unroll the loop
     for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
         PP = modulo(((int)r_cc_points + m -K ),(cc*N)); 
            rtemp[m] = Uj[PP]; //2

         P = (K*K-(cc_points-(r_cc_points+(double)(m-K)))*(cc_points-(r_cc_points+(double)(m-K))));
         if(P<0.) {tempd=rsqrt(-P); phi_cap_s[m] = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa/tempd))*tempd);  }
         else if(P>0.) {tempd=rsqrt(P); phi_cap_s[m] = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa/tempd))*tempd); }
         else phi_cap_s[m] = alfa/pi_double;  
     }

     #pragma unroll //unroll the loop
     for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
         temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s[m]*rtemp[m].x; 
           temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s[m]*rtemp[m].y; 
     } 

     result[i] = temp; 
     }
 }
```

In particular:
1) I moved the global memory variable Uj to the register rtemp array of size 2*K+1 (K is a constant equal to 6 in my case);
2) I moved the variable phi_cap_s to a 2*K+1 sized register;
3) I used the if ... else statements instead of the three previously used if's (the conditions P<0. and P>0. have the same occurrence probability);
3) I defined extra variables for the square root;
4) I used rsqrt instead of sqrt (as long as I know, the sqrt() is calculated by CUDA as 1/rsqrt());

I added each new feature once at a time, verifying the improvement against the original version, but I must say that none of them gave me any relevant improvement.

The execution speed is limited by:
1) the calculation of the sin/sinh functions (about 40% of the time); is there any way to calculate them in double precision arithmetics by somehow exploiting intrinsic math as a "starting guess"?
2) the fact that many threads end up to access the same global memory locations Uj[PP] due to the mapping index PP; one possibility to avoid it would be using shared memory, but this would imply a strong thread cooperation.

My question is. Am I done? Namely, is there any mean to improve the code? I profiled the code by the NVIDIA Visual Profiler and here are the results:

```
IPC = 1.939 (compute capability 2.1);
Global Memory Load Efficiency = 38.9%;
Global Memory Store Efficiency = 18.8%;
Warp Execution Efficiency = 97%;
Instruction Replay Overhead = 0.7%;
```

Finally, I would like to notice that this discussion is linked to the discussion at [CUDA: 1-dimensional cubic spline interpolation in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859322/cuda-1-dimensional-cubic-spline-interpolation-in-cuda)

**VERSION USING SHARED MEMORY**

I have made a feasibility study on using shared memory. I have considered `N=64` so that the whole `Uj` fits the shared memory. Below is the code (basically is my original version)

```
    __global__ void interpolation_shared(cufftDoubleComplex *Uj, double *points, cufftDoubleComplex *result, int N, int M)
 {
         int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

     int PP;
     double P;
     const double alfa=(2.-1./cc)*pi_double-0.01;
     double phi_cap_s;
     cufftDoubleComplex temp;

     double cc_points=cc*points[i];
     double r_cc_points=rint(cc*points[i]);

     temp = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.,0.);

     __shared__ cufftDoubleComplex Uj_shared[128];

     if (threadIdx.x < cc*N) Uj_shared[threadIdx.x]=Uj[threadIdx.x];

     if(i<M) {  
         for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
         P = (K*K-(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K))*(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K)));

         if(P>0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa*sqrt(P)))/sqrt(P));  
         if(P<0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa*sqrt(-P)))/sqrt(-P));  
         if(P==0.) phi_cap_s = alfa/pi_double;        

         PP = modulo((r_cc_points + m -K ),(cc*N)); 
         temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s*Uj_shared[PP].x; 
         temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s*Uj_shared[PP].y; 
      } 

      result[i] = temp; 
    }
 }
```

The result again does not improve significantly, although this might depend on the small size of the input array.

**VERBOSE PTXAS OUTPUT**

```
ptxas : info : Compiling entry function '_Z13interpolationP7double2PdS0_ii' for 'sm_20'
ptxas : info : Function properties for _Z13interpolationP7double2PdS0_ii
  352 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas : info : Used 55 registers, 456 bytes cumulative stack size, 52 bytes cmem[0]
```

**VALUES OF P, FOR FIRST WARP AND m=0**

```
 0.0124300933082964
 0.0127183892149176
 0.0135847002913749
 0.0161796378170038
 0.0155488126345702
 0.0138890822153499
 0.0121163187739057
 0.0119998374528905
 0.0131600831194518
 0.0109574866163769
 0.00962949548477354
 0.00695850974164358
 0.00446426651940612
 0.00423369284281705
 0.00632921297092537
 0.00655137618976198
 0.00810202954519923
 0.00597974034698723
 0.0076811348379735
 0.00604267951733561
 0.00402922460255439
 0.00111841719893846
 -0.00180949615796777
 -0.00246283218698551
 -0.00183256444286428
 -0.000462696661685413
 0.000725108980390132
 -0.00126793006072035
 0.00152263101649197
 0.0022499598348702
 0.00463681632275836
 0.00359856091027666
```

**MODULO FUNCTION**

```
__device__ int modulo(int val, int modulus)
{
   if(val > 0) return val%modulus;
   else
   {
       int P = (-val)%modulus;
       if(P > 0) return modulus -P;
       else return 0;
   }
}
```

**MODULO FUNCTION OPTIMIZED ACCORDING TO ANSWER**

```
__device__ int modulo(int val, int _mod)
{
    if(val > 0) return val&(_mod-1);
    else
    {
        int P = (-val)&(_mod-1);
        if(P > 0) return _mod -P;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I plugged `(1 / pi) * ((sin(A * sqrt(P))) / sqrt(P))` into Wolfram Alpha and it came up with an alternate form that has no `sin()`. But it has two exponents and lots of other stuff. Probably wouldn't be worth it. Can you use abs(P) instead of the `if`s? I don't think there's much you can do with the expression, in general. DP is expensive on GPUs (both in performance and dollars).

Comment: How efficient is global memory acess? Try adding additional variables when reading from it for `Uj[PP]` (To remove possibility of 2 reads instead of one). Try the same for `sqrt()`. I'm not sure if 2 calls here are optimized. Is `Uj` large? Can you move it to constant memory? OR How it's accessed by different threads in one block? (Sorry, can't guess just from code) May be you can cache it in shared memory?

Comment: One thing to do when random access is not avoidable is to process several values at the same time. E.g. if you want to add two things together a + b, first fetch a1 to a register, then b1, a2,b2,b3,b4... then you add them together in the fetched order, a1+b1, a2+b2... In my application I find that between 4 and 8 values processed per thread gives a good boost in performance. If you look here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Au1A39JI-BwHdHpESVZRODZoM2VoTzFtcG91bW1mVlE#gid=1 I compare blocksizes and values processed per thread. with 2 vs 4 values processed I gain up to double speed!.

Comment: @RogerDahl Unfortunately, I do not believe that expressing the functions by other functions will change things. I cannot even use abs(P) instead of the `if`s since the involved functions are different (`sin` and `sinh`). I have tried using texture memory for Uj, instead of global memory (for a different version using single precision floating point arithmetics), but the version with texture memory is even slower. I'm trying using now dynamic parallelism, see  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033997/cuda-dynamic-parallelism), but unsuccessfully for the moment.

Comment: @OlegTitov Sorry, but I do not understand why defining a variable for `sqrt` should help. The two `sqrt`s are mutually exclusive. Concerning constant memory, unfortunately I cannot fit `Uj` to constant memory. I  believe that neither shared memory will help since the different threads use different - nonoverlapping - sliding interpolation windows for which the values of `Uj` are different.

Comment: @ks6g10 Thanks for your answer. Could you please be more specific? Unfortunately, I do not know which values of `Uj` to access until I calculate the index `PP`. It would help if you have any written document (e.g., paper/book) with more details. If you are interested, I'm trying to solve the problem by dynamic parallelism, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033997/cuda-dynamic-parallelism).

Comment: @JackOLantern `((sinh(alfa*sqrt(P)))/sqrt(P))` - here you have 2 `sqrt(P)` I was talking about this equation. I'm not sure if compiler somehow optimizes it.

Comment: @OlegTitov Yes, you are right that there are two calls to `sqrt(P)`. I have just tried to define a new variable for `sqrt(P)` and `sqrt(-P)`, but nothing relevant changes. Thanks.

Comment: Have you determined if your algorithm is compute bound or memory bound? If the double precision throughput you're getting is close to the max possible for your chip, I don't think there's anything more you can do.

Comment: @RogerDahl I have edited my first post and added a revised version of the code according to the received comments and answers, but unfortunately without improvements. I have posted also some numbers provided by the NVIDIA Visual Profiler. My question is: Am I done with the code or is there any possibility to improve it?

Comment: @JackOLantern: To answer that question, we need to find out what the max IPC is for CC 2.1 and what max IPC would be if it was possible to run a pure DP instruction mix. I'm going to add an SO question for that.

Comment: How is the occupancy? if you could also compile with -Xptxas –v and show us the result. And when you profile, could you show us what the `instruction replay overhead` is!

Comment: @JackOLantern From your other posts you say you are using Tesla K20 (I am jelly), and from you numbers you say you compile for CC 2.1, why not 3.5?

Comment: @RogerDahl Thanks Roger. I will wait for your information. I have also made a small feasibility study on using the shared memory, but it seems it does not help (see the edited version of the post).

Comment: @ks6g10 I have added the Instruction Replay Overhead (which is 0.7% for that kernel) to the edited version of the post. I will compile with -Xptxas –v and let you know the results when I will figure out how to do that with Visual Studio 2010. Concerning the compute capability, I'm currently testing this code on a GT 540M card and compiling with compute capability 2.0. If you refer to [CUDA dynamic parallelism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033997/cuda-dynamic-parallelism), yes I have also the availability of K20 cards to make dynamic parallelism tests, hoping to improve the results.

Comment: @JackOLantern Hm, that is quite low, with my application which is also random access I get around 45% instruction replay overhead.

What numbers are you getting for variable P? only numbers in base 2?

Comment: @ks6g10 I revised the post with verbose PTXAS output. From [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551923/in-cuda-profiler-nvvp-what-does-the-shared-global-memory-replay-overhead-mean), I understand that the `instruction replay overhead` should be ideally zero. Does it mean that the code performs good? I have also added the values of `P` I obtain for the first warp and `m=0`.

Comment: @JackOLantern an `instruction replay overhead` of 0.7% means that you are more of less not slowed down by blocked warps, which means you can not really improve the performance much unless you optimize the instruction usage. Will update my post with one optimization.

Comment: @JackOLantern How is your compile line? have you turned on optimization -O3 and turned off debugging -G? As with debugging on, the compiler can not optimize the kernel. Further, all you can really do is try to reduce instructions and registers used. As of now you use 56 registers, that means your occupancy may suffer, what happens if you set --maxrregcount to e.g. 26-32. This will cause the registers to spill to local memory but it may speed up your execution.

Comment: @ks6g10 Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried to perform a full optimization (/Ox in Visual Studio 2010) and I noticed a slight improvement in execution speed. Forcing maxrregcount to the range you mentioned provided a slight decrease in performance. If I understand good, fixing a maxrregcount forces to avoid using registers and to go to local memory, right? I'm wondering why should this help since, as long as I know, using registers should be the best you could do. Probably this presentation would help [link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/register_spilling.pdf)

Comment: @JackOLantern Yes `--maxregcount` forces it to go to local memory(which is global memory more or less), however, it allows you to increase your occupancy and in some cases you may benefit. But you are correct, registers is the fastest. But if you use too many, you will use less resources. What you should do now is try to reduce the amount of registers used to increase your occupancy, which I think suffers greatly due to the amount of registers used. Also, you may reduce the amount of registers used by also passing `-Xptxas –v,-abi=no`.

Comment: @JackOLantern Further, with 55 registers used, you will have an occupancy of 33% according to the Cuda occupancy calculator. However, occupancy does not always correlate with faster runtime, as you can achieve faster runtime with larger amount of registers used. What is your blocksize?

Comment: @ks6g10 `blocksize=64`. For lower values, the code performance worsens. I will let you know about `Xptxas –v,-abi=no` as long as I figure out how to do it in Visual Studio 2010. Is this option equivalent to manually setting the number of registers, or it is something automatic optimized by the compiler?

Comment: @JackOLantern removing the ABI (Application Binary Interface) disables cuda from generating stack frames and pointers used if you do recursion. It frees up further registers for you to use.

Comment: @JackOLantern Also could you post the code for the modulo function, just want to see if it can be improved any.

Comment: @JackOLantern what is the constant cc set to?

Comment: @ks6g10 I have posted the code for the modulo function. Also, in my application `cc=2`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JackOLantern Updated for the modulus function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//your code above
cufftDoubleComplex rtemp[(2*K+1)] //if it fits into available registers, assumes K is a constant

if(i<M) {   
#pragma unroll //unroll the loop
    for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {

        PP = modulo((r_cc_points + m -K ),(cc*N)); 
        rtemp[m] = Uj[PP]; //2
    }
#pragma unroll
    for(nt m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
        P = (K*K-(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K))*(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K)));
        // 1
        if(P>0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa*sqrt(P)))/sqrt(P));  
        else if(P<0.)  phi_cap_s = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa*sqrt(-P)))/sqrt(-P));   
        else phi_cap_s = alfa/pi_double;  

        temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s*rtemp[m].x; //3
        temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s*rtemp[m].y; 
    }

    result[i] = temp; 
}
```

### Explanation

1. Added else if and else as these conditions are mutually exclusive, if you could, you should order the statements after probability of occurrence.  E.g. if P<0. most of the times, you should evaluate that first.
2. This will fetch the requested memory to multiple registers, what you did before may have certainly caused a block on that thread due to not having the memory available in time for calculation. And keep in mind that if one thread blocks in a warp, the whole warp is blocked. If not enough warps in the ready queue, the program will block until any warp is ready.
3. We have now moved the calculations further forward in time in order to compensate for the bad memory access, hopefully the calculations done previously have compensated for the bad access pattern.

The reason why this should work is the following:

A request from memory that is in GMEM is around >~400-600 ticks. If a thread tries to perform operations on memory that is not available at time, it will block. That means if each memory request does not live in L1-L2 each warp have to wait that time or more until it can continue.

What I suspect is that `temp.x+phi_cap_s*Uj[PP].x` is doing just that. By staging (step 2) each memory transfer to a register, and moving on to stage the next you will hide the latency by allowing you to do other work while the memory is transfered.

By the time you reach step 3 the memory is hopefully available or you have to wait less time.

If `rtemp` does not fit into the registers to achieve 100% occupancy you may have to do it in batches.

You could also try to make `phi_cap_s` into an array and put it into the first loop like this:

```
#pragma unroll //unroll the loop
    for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
        //stage memory first
        PP = modulo((r_cc_points + m -K ),(cc*N)); 
        rtemp[m] = Uj[PP]; //2

        P = (K*K-(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K))*(cc_points-(r_cc_points+m-K)));
        // 1
        if(P>0.)  phi_cap_s[m] = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa*sqrt(P)))/sqrt(P));  
        else if(P<0.)  phi_cap_s[m] = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa*sqrt(-P)))/sqrt(-P));   
        else phi_cap_s[m] = alfa/pi_double; 

    }
#pragma unroll
    for(nt m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
        temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s[m]*rtemp[m].x; //3
        temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s[m]*rtemp[m].y; 
    }
```

### Edit

Expression

```
P = (K*K-(cc_points-(r_cc_points+(double)(m-K)))*(cc_points-(r_cc_points+(double)(m-K))));
```

Can be broken down into:

```
const double cc_diff = cc_points-r_cc_points;
double exp = cc_diff - (double)(m-K);
exp *= exp;
P = (K*K-exp);
```

Which may reduce the number of instructions used.

### Edit 2

```
__global__ void interpolation(cufftDoubleComplex *Uj, double *points, cufftDoubleComplex *result, int N, int M)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    int PP;
    double P,tempd;


    cufftDoubleComplex rtemp[(2*K+1)];
    double phi_cap_s[2*K+1];

    if(i<M) {
         const double cc_points=cc*points[i];
         cufftDoubleComplex temp = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.,0.);

         const double alfa=(2.-1./cc)*pi_double-0.01;


         const double r_cc_points=rint(cc_points);
         const double cc_diff = cc_points-r_cc_points;

     #pragma unroll //unroll the loop
         for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
             PP = m-k; //reuse PP
             double exp = cc_diff - (double)(PP); //stage exp to be used later, will explain

             PP = modulo(((int)r_cc_points + PP ),(cc*N)); 
             rtemp[m] = Uj[PP]; //2


             exp *= exp;
             P = (K*K-exp);

             if(P<0.) {tempd=rsqrt(-P); phi_cap_s[m] = (1./pi_double)*((sin(alfa/tempd))*tempd);  }
             else if(P>0.) {tempd=rsqrt(P); phi_cap_s[m] = (1./pi_double)*((sinh(alfa/tempd))*tempd); }
             else phi_cap_s[m] = alfa/pi_double;  
         }

     #pragma unroll //unroll the loop
         for(int m=0; m<(2*K+1); m++) {
             temp.x = temp.x+phi_cap_s[m]*rtemp[m].x; 
             temp.y = temp.y+phi_cap_s[m]*rtemp[m].y; 
         } 

     result[i] = temp; 
     }
 }
```

What I have done is moved in all the calculations inside the if statement to free up some resources both in terms of calculations but also memory fetch, do not know the divergence you have on the first if statement `if(i<M)`. As `m-K` appeared twice in the code, I first put it in `PP` to be used when you calculate `exp` and `PP`.

What else you can do is to try and order you instructions so that, if you set a variable, make as many instruction in in between the next usage of said variable as possible, as it takes ~20 tics for it to be set into the registers. Hence, I put the constant cc_diff at the top, however, as this is only a one of instruction, it may not show any benefit.

### Modulo function

```
__device__ modulo(int val, int _mod) {
    int p = (val&(_mod-1));// as modulo is always the power of 2
    if(val < 0) {
        return _mod - p;
    } else {
        return p;
    }
}
```

As we have `_mod` always as an integer of power of 2(`cc = 2, N = 64, cc*N = 128`), we can use this function instead of the mod operator. This should be "much" faster. Check it though so I have the arithmetic correct. It is from [Optimizing Cuda - Part II Nvidia](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_Further_CUDA_Optimization.pdf&ei=kwTmUIeeFerw4QTohoCIAg&usg=AFQjCNH2RKW7cJyidG54T4LBdRg7-mKhsA&sig2=cUz1vOV-5xD0mLkqC1rCbw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bGE) page 14.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I revised my initial post also according to your answer, but unfortunately without significant improvements. Please, take a look anyway. I have a question. According to your solution, Uj is being loaded from global memory to registers while the thread can do other operations in the meanwhile, which seems reasonable. But do I need also a __syncthreads() before using the register values, namely, before the last for loop?

Comment: @JackOLantern `__syncthreads()` is not needed as you are not doing anything that involves inter thread communication using shared memory. I.e. the threads are not dependent on each other. I will take a look at the updated one.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I do not need __syncthreads(), but if memory transfer and computation overlap, how may I be sure that the values of Uj are really available (namely, their load has been accomplished) in rtemp before starting the last loop calculating temp?

Comment: If the values are not loaded into the registers yet, the thread and warp will be blocked. So you are safe without __syncthreads, as it will not do computations if the value is not in there yet.

Comment: I have revised the code according to your revised answer. The IPC improved from 1.912 to 1.936. Thanks.

Comment: @JackOLantern Great it worked! did you put cc_diff, inside or outside of the for loop, it should reside outside of the for loop as it does not change with time. Will update one more thing.

Comment: `cc_diff` was already moved outside the loop. Will try your new code and answer to the other pending questions of yours tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: In the new "modulo" function, you are basically suggesting the trick foo%n equivalent to (but faster than) foo&(n-1) if n is a power of two. I have then revised my "modulo" function (see revised post - your version was not fully arithmetically equivalent). By the trick you mentioned, the IPC further raised to 1.958. Thanks!

Comment: I have done the two further optimizations in your last revised code suggestion. It seems that moving the variable declarations inside the `if` statement reduces the IPC. However, if I leave the declarations as they are (outside the `if` statement) and I exploit your rearrangement of operations up to the `if (P<0.)` statement, then the IPC further raises to `1.964`. Thanks again! I have however a question. Is there any reason for not recommending to move the register array declarations `cufftDoubleComplex rtemp[(2*K+1)];` and `double phi_cap_s[2*K+1];` inside the `if (i<M)` statement? Thanks.

Comment: From a comparison between the original and the optimized interpolation kernels, the original has better IPC and IRO values (`2.027` and `0.3%`, respectively, for the original version versus `1.964` and `0.7%`, respectively, for the optimized version), while the original takes longer (`965ms` against `922ms`). Is there an explanation for that?

Comment: @JackOLantern Regarding the register decelerations, I was thinking as it have to allocate enough registers to allow all divergence paths as it can not allocate registers on the fly, it will always allocate the maximum registers needed. So no optimality can be achieved there. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @JackOLantern Regarding IPC, as you before did calculations not needed by divergent kernels, it may improve the IPC and IRO as you calculate things not used anywhere else. But this also introduces more latencies as you only have a limited number of SFUs and floating point arithmetic units. As you also did a memory request this reduces your effective bandwidth as these values fetched will not be used by the divergent threads. And in the end, if one fully optimized method is faster than another method, even though it got worse values(IPC,IRO...) you should go for the faster.

Answer (score 0):

One optimization you probably would want to look into is to use fast math. Use intrinsics math functions and compile with -use-fast-math option.

[intrinsics math](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE_gfa0ea4b2cee94521792ead0deb03addb.html)

Comment: I'm not using intrinsics math since it is approximate and I want full double precision.

Comment: Is the access to Uj[PP] memory bounded within a block? If so, how about using shared memory?

Comment: I have revised my original post and added also a comment on the use of shared memory.

Comment: I have re-revised the post and added the result of a feasibility study on using the shared memory.